# is there any method to trigger error message when response is received in revalidate?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, react-final-form

I am integrating react-final-from with revalidate for validation, **there is one separate API for checking if the email already in system.** If it is I receive an message from response that it exists or vice versa.
how do I trigger error message **manually when I receive the response from api in reavalidate**.
**I am using react with typescript and for validation revalidate for forms react-final-form**

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You return a `Promise` from the validation function.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wy7z7q5zx5).